# How to display clicked option inside select element as an active?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Whenever I select an option from select dropdown, it refreshes and the selected value is not displayed rather the first option is displayed everytime however it function according to the selected option.
What I want is clicked option to be displayed inside select field rather than first option.

For instance;

```
<select id="trend" class="form-ct" name="gender_filter" onchange="this.form.submit();">
   <option value="M">Man</option>
   <option value="F">Woman</option>
   <option value="O">Other</option>   
</select>
```

Comment: Any change to this select submits your form, so I suppose the form gets reloaded. You'll have to store the value somewhere, either on JS side (`localStorage` / `sessionStorage`), or on PHP side, and retrieve it on load.

Comment: Thanks Jeto. Any tweaks?

Comment: It depends on quite a few things. Does that gender get stored somewhere in your system/database? If so, better to simply retrieve it from there.

Comment: after changing the select option, pass the selected value as a param to your url. after the page loads, you get the selected value using $_GET option